# Java Mail API is not working?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class MailSender {

    private Session session;
    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    public MailSender(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        init(username, password);
    }

    public final void init(String username, String password) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(MailSender.this.username, MailSender.this.password);
            }
        });

    }

    public boolean send(String recipient, String subject, String body) {
        boolean status = false;
        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);
            Transport.send(message);
            status = true;

        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MailSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return status;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MailSender mailer = new MailSender("ganeshdatapoint@gmail.com", "******");
        //Userprojects u=new Userprojects();
        boolean status = mailer.send("ganeshdatapoint@gmail.com", "Testing Subject", "Testing message");
        System.out.println(status);
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

I have used correct login Email ID and Password to compile & execute this program by using JavamailAPI and my runabble batch file commands are given below

Authenitication failed exception : 534.5.7.14 https://account.google.com/continousSignIn

Comment: "giving the exceptions as specified below" and then not specified. Is this one of those ingenious interview questions where we have to discover for outselves? Is that final period `.` a miniature graphic image actually holding the exception as micro-text? Or did you just forget to include it?

Comment: Authenitication failed exception : 534.5.7.14 https://account.google.com/continousSignIn

Comment: Well clearly you have *not* used the correct login ID and password.

Comment: Maybe Gmail is unhappy that you're trying to sign in too often and failing?  Have you enabled [less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)?

Comment: Do you have the Google 2 Step Verification?  If so, you must generate a new password for your application, your normal password will not work.

https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords

Answer (score 3):

The code ran fine here.

I think you have provided an incorrect user name and/or password. If you have enabled two-way authentication, please also ensure that you are providing the correct [**Application Specific Password**](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en).

Unrelated to your problem - The parameters used in the init method are never used.

So you can either:

- Removed the arguments from your `init` method, i.e, `init()`;
- Pass `MailSender` instance to `init` method, i.e, `init(this);`

i.e,

```
public final void init() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(MailSender.this.username, MailSender.this.password);
        }
    });
}
```

or

```
public final void init(MailSender mailSender) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(mailSender.username, mailSender.password);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Working fine Thanks You.   :)

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept this answer, that will mark this post as solved and people who find this question using google can have more assurance that the answer is correct. :)